# TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

When following [Getting started with Postgres in your React app](https://blog.logrocket.com/getting-started-with-postgres-in-your-react-app/), at the point where you process and export the getMerchants, createMerchant, and deleteMerchant functions, I am getting this error -- TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined, what is going on here?? It is probably something very small I am missing. There error occurs at getMerchants and resolve(results.rows)

```js
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'my_user',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'my_database',
    password: 'root',
    port: 5432,
});

const getMerchants = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM userIds ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }
            resolve(results.rows);
        })
    })
}
const createMerchant = (body) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const { name, email } = body
        pool.query('INSERT INTO userIds (name, email) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *', [name, email], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }
            resolve(`A new merchant has been added added: ${results.rows[0]}`)
        })
    })
}
const deleteMerchant = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const id = parseInt(Request.params.id)
        pool.query('DELETE FROM userIds WHERE id = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }
            resolve(`Merchant deleted with ID: ${id}`)
        })
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getMerchants,
    createMerchant,
    deleteMerchant,
}
```

Comment: Second parameter for `query` is the query parameters, and not a callback function. Pass in `[]`, if you do not have parameters. Other than that, your code looks largely redundant. You should follow proper async pattern that library offers, and not re-create all those useless promises.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment:

> Second parameter for query is the query parameters, and not a callback function. Pass in `[]`, if you do not have parameters. Other than that, your code looks largely redundant. You should follow proper async pattern that library offers, and not re-create all those useless promises...

```js
const getMerchants = () => pool.query('SELECT * FROM userIds ORDER BY id ASC');
```

And then use it like this:

```js
const {rows} = await getMerchants();
```

Comment: The code snippet was taken from a [blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/getting-started-with-postgres-in-your-react-app/), and I do not want to change the whole structure. How could the error be solved if you do not take out the Promises? I am looking for the smallest change possible to stay in line with the guide.

Comment: Hi vitaly-t Please look I think this is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### Right code, wrong password

The code itself is right! The error is thrown:

1. if you have not set a password at all, or
2. if you enter a wrong password. For example, I accidentally copied 'root' as a password from the guide, although I had set the password of `my_user` to 'postgres'. When everything else was already running and only the password was wrong, you get the same error.

The error in detail:

```
myuser@mypc:~/project/node-postgres$ node index.js

App running on port 3001.
/home/myuser/myproject/node-postgres/merchant_model.js:17
      resolve(results.rows);
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined
    at pool.query (/home/myuser/myproject/node-postgres/merchant_model.js:17:23)
    at PendingItem.connect [as callback] (/home/myuser/myproject/node-postgres/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:363:16)
    at Client.client.connect [as _connectionCallback] (/home/myuser/myproject/node-postgres/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:246:23)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/home/myuser/myproject/node-postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (/home/myuser/myproject/node-postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:325:19)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at parse (/home/myuser/myproject/node-postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:12)
    at Parser.parse (/home/myuser/myproject/node-postgres/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.stream.on (/home/myuser/myproject/node-postgres/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

I could find out the solution for this by following the guide at [Getting started with Postgres in your React app: an end to end example](https://github.com/nsebhastian/react-node-postgres) where you also find more about the code that was used here. For digging deeper into this, [How to quickly build an API using Node.js & PostgreSQL](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-quickly-build-api-using-nodejs-postgresql) might help as well. To test this, you need to install PostgreSQL (or use a Webserver, but then, you will need SSL, see [How to create a pool object in javascript that can connect to a database backend using SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142073/how-to-create-a-pool-object-in-javascript-that-can-connect-to-a-database-backend)) and create a "Merchant" table in the database as it is done in the guide.

As the files of the tutorial do not have any error, the problem of the question happens most probably (as in my case) because you have not fully followed the guide about how to set up the database role and password. You can check whether your settings are right by running, depending on whether you have chosen the guide's `my_user` or the standard `postgres` user to connect (if the latter, change the pool settings in `merchant_model.js` to `postgres` user):

```
psql -d my_database -U my_user
```

or:

```
psql -d my_database -U postgres
```

It should ask for a password:

```
Password for user postgres/my_user:
```

If your password tries are not accepted (standard test password is often `postgres` or the guide uses `root`), you probably do not have any password set, so easy. This was in my case, since the fresh install of PostgreSQL does not give the superuser `postgres` a password, neither has any other role that you create! It just did not catch my attention because I always used

```
sudo su postgres
```

to connect, which just asks you for the password of your Linux user, not that of the postgres user.

Thus: you must use a `postgres` (or `my_user`) user that has a password. You need to follow [Getting error: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres", when trying to get pgsql working with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735105/11154841) in order to give postgres a password, and if you want to use another user like `my_user`, give it a password as well.

Only then, you get the connection done. And the error will disappear.

#### Outlook

When you have added the two files from the repository:

- merchant_model.js (the one from the guide or the compact version above)
- index.js (from the guide)

[image]

to the "node-postgres" directory, being in the project directory, you can run it with `node index.js`.

If that runs, you should see

```
App running on port 3001.
```

in the command prompt, with the command still running. Then you open a browser and enter `localhost:3001` to see the backend:

[image]

When you then follow the guide and add the files from the repository:

- App.js
- index.js

[image]

to the "react-postgres\src" directory, you can run:

```
npm start
```

to see the frontend:

[image]

Try the `Add` button:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

#### PS: Bad coding? Probably not!

The first answer is wrong in saying that the alleged "bad coding" is the cause of the error. **You can use the full copies of the guide's github repository and everything will work**, since the error comes from somthing else in the end. Yet, the code above *may* be bad coding, at least, [count null entries in database column in a RESTfull way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68361045/11154841) also uses the suggested `await`. I doubt that is that bad since it is working well, and when I later ran the code without the Promises on react-postgres, I vaguely remember having had a sort of message that you should use error handlers. Yet, for anyone interested, here is the advice of the first answer put into practice, it works, the "rows" error disappears, but that is just because the "rows" are not in the code anymore :))).

`merchant_model.js`:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'my_user',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'my_database',
  password: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
});    

const getMerchants = () => pool.query('SELECT * FROM Merchants ORDER BY id ASC') 

const createMerchant = (body) => {
    const { name, email } = body
    pool.query('INSERT INTO Merchants (name, email) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *', [name, email])
}

const deleteMerchant = () => {
    const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
    pool.query('DELETE FROM Merchants WHERE ID = $1', [id])
}

module.exports = {
  getMerchants,
  createMerchant,
  deleteMerchant,
}
```

Whether you use the code with or without Promises is up to you, perhaps one should rather stick to the guide and use it with Promises.