# How to create a pool object in javascript that can connect to a database backend using SSL?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, ssl

I followed a guide on how to create a Node JS backend on PostgreSQL and a ReactJS frontend, which is working well, see [here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69085149/11154841).

The js pool object of the quide looks as follows:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'my_user',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'my_database',
  password: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
});
```

I tried doing the same with a PostgreSQL Webserver using SSL encryption. This question is not tagged `postgresql` since the pool looks the same for mysql and other databases. It is also not tagged `Linux` since it should work the same on other OS.

How to create a pool object from the Pool class in javascript that can connect to a PostgreSQL backend using SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the certificate, call it `server-certificate.pem`, in a place with a static path starting with `/` (`~` for your user's home directory does not work). Therefore, you need to move it to a static place.

I copied the file to a newly created directory `certificates`, but that is of course up to you. You will need super user rights for this.

```
/etc/certificates/server-certificate.pem
```

You need to load `fs` and use it in the SSL part, see [How to establish a secure connection (SSL) from a Node.js API to an AWS RDS](https://medium.com/nexton/how-to-establish-a-secure-connection-from-a-node-js-api-to-an-aws-rds-f79c5daa2ea5).

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const fs = require('fs');
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'my_user',
  host: 'my_host',
  database: 'my_database',
  password: 'my_password',
  port: 22222,
  ssl: {
    ca: fs
      .readFileSync("/etc/certificates/server-certificate.pem")
      .toString()
  }
});
```